# How could I implement TabView page switching as a function of a selected date from DatePicker?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-datepicker

I've implemented the following code for my TabView and a DatePicker. I can currently slide between the three pages. And I can use the DatePicker to select between the 3 permitted days

```
import SwiftUI

struct DailyOverviewTab: View {
   @State private var date = Date()

   let dateRange: ClosedRange<Date> = {
      let calendar = Calendar.current
      let startComponents = DateComponents(year: 2024, month: 5, day: 6)
      let endComponents = DateComponents(year: 2024, month, 5, day: 8)
      return calendar.date(from: startComponents)! ... calendar.date(from: endComponents)
   }()

   var body: some View {
      TabView() {
         Six_May()
            .tag(1)
         Seven_May()
            .tag(2)
         Eight_May()
            .tag(3)
      }
      .tabViewStyle(.page)
      .foregroundColor(.green)
      
      DatePicker("", selection: $date, in: dateRange, displayedComponents: [.date])
         .datePickerStyle(.compact)
         .labelsHidden()
   }
}
```

However, I don't know how to use the selected date in order to switch pages. I would like to be able to switch pages both by swiping and by using the date in the DatePicker to go to a specific page. I only have 3 pages now, but I anticipate having much more, so using a calendar to go to a specific page would be ideal.

I tried using `date.formatted(date: .complete, time: .omitted)` to assign the selected date to a variable. I don't know how to use this variable to change the TabView though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this approach, using the `$date` in both the TabView selection, **and** the DatePicker `...to be able to switch pages both by swiping and by using the date in the DatePicker to go to a specific page.`
Note the `.tag()` in the `TabView`. You will have to adjust the logic when dates not in the range are selected, and take into account local timezone if required.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        DailyOverviewTab()
    }
}

struct DailyOverviewTab: View {
    @State private var date = Date()

    let dateRange: ClosedRange<Date> = {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let startComponents = DateComponents(year: 2024, month: 5, day: 6)
        let endComponents = DateComponents(year: 2024, month: 5, day: 8)
        return calendar.date(from: startComponents)! ... calendar.date(from: endComponents)!
    }()
    
    let sixmay = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2024, month: 5, day: 6))!
    let sevenmay = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2024, month: 5, day: 7))!
    let eightmay = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2024, month: 5, day: 8))!
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $date) {
            Six_May().tag(sixmay)
            Seven_May().tag(sevenmay)
            Eight_May().tag(eightmay)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
        .foregroundColor(.green)
        
        DatePicker("", selection: $date, in: dateRange, displayedComponents: [.date])
            .datePickerStyle(.compact)
            .labelsHidden()
            .onAppear {
                date = dateRange.lowerBound
            }
    }
    
}

struct Six_May: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Six_May")
    }
}
struct Seven_May: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Seven_May")
    }
}
struct Eight_May: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Eight_May")
    }
}
```